# when click navigation button, onSlideChange run twice

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swiper.js

I made multiple slides per group with Swiper.js (Swiper@8.4.6 and React@^18)
But when clicking navigation button at the first slides's group,  onSlideChange function runs twice, so it passes middle group and stop at last group. From the last group, it also passes middle one.
Though I set `loop: true` at swiper config, it can be solved but I am looking for other ways on when loop option is false.

How can I run only one phase skipped?

Thank you for your help.

```
import SwiperCore, { Navigation } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper as SwiperReact, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';


export function LineCardSwiper({ contents }: SwiperProps) {
  const [swiper, setSwiper] = useState<SwiperCore>();
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleChangeIndex = (props: SwiperCore) => {
    const newIndex = Math.floor(props.activeIndex / 4);
    setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
    console.log('newIndex', newIndex);
  };

  const swiperOption = {
    modules: [Navigation],
    autoHeight: true,
    navigation: {
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    },
    spaceBetween: 10,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 1.4,
    slidesPerGroup: 1,
    breakpoints: {
      768: {
        touchRatio: 0,
        slidesPerView: 4,
        slidesPerGroup: 4,
        centeredSlides: false,
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SwiperWrapStyle
        getNaviStyle={getNaviStyle}
        getColorStyle={getColorStyle}
      >
        <div className='swiper-button-prev'>
          <span />
        </div>
        <div className='swiper-button-next'>
          <span />
        </div>

        <SwiperReact
          onSwiper={(swiper: SwiperCore) => setSwiper(swiper)}
          onSlideChange={(swiper: SwiperCore) => handleChangeIndex(swiper)}
          {...swiperOption}
        >
          {SlideContents}
        </SwiperReact>
      </SwiperWrapStyle>
    </>
  );
}
```

I checked it runs twice by using debugger, and looked for other reference source at official document and stackoverflow, and Swiper github to find similar issues and solution.